# Read/Write to linux Pipe using Java

Tags: java, pipe, named-pipes

My query is on what is the best way to read / write to a linux Pipe in Java? I already am using the java.io.RandomAccessFile like

```
   RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("/dev/zap/16", "rw");
```

and then passing it to worker thread which reads it after every 2ms as

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
  file.read(buffer);
```

It does read it from Pipe, but I suspect that some bytes are overwritten. Do you know how linux (ubuntu) handles the buffer for pipe's?

Comment: What is the connection to asterisk?

Comment: Actually the /dev/zap/16 is created by Zaptel driver used for Asterisk when you have SS7 card installed on your machine. Asterisk has module that reads this pipe but is in native code. I am trying to get this working on Java. Out of topic but if any of you trying to install Asterisk + SS7 here is my experience http://amitbhayani.blogspot.com/2009/04/asterisk-ss7.html

Answer (score 11):

I haven't ever tried this myself but what your doing feels just wrong. Linux pipes are First in - First out (FIFO) by definition. Hence you should only be able to read bytes in the same order as you've written them - not randomly. I'd suggest to use a normal `File` instead and it should work fine.

Comment: Do you mean a normal `FileInputStream`? That's what I'd try first, too.

Comment: `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` respectively, yes

Comment: Interesting... Every tutorial I found on pipes in java is using RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 6):

Pipes aren't handled in any way special by Java as far as I know. You simply open the file for writing and write to it.

You can't really "overwrite" anything in a pipe, since you can't seek in a pipe. For the same reason a `RandomAccessFile` isn't the smartest choice to use (since a pipe is explicitely *not* a random access file). I'd suggest using a `FileOutputStream` instead.

Also note that `read()` is not guaranteed to read until the buffer is full! It can read a single byte as well and you need to check its return value and possibly loop to read the full buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be flushing after writing, so do OutputStream.flush() often and read may be a byte at time, at least to see if your data is getting thru. 
e.g. to start with open a named pipe in readonly mode(FileInputStream) in process1, open it in write mode(FileOutputStream ) in process2, so anything you write in process2 will be read in process1.

also read

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node15.html
http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/2.10.5.shtml
http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/2.10.6.shtml